# Weird validation error handling in Micronaut

Tags: validation, grails-orm, micronaut

I have a controller action to serve my react front-end. It requires the validation messages in the special format:

```java
  @Transactional
  @Post( uri = '{/id}', consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
  HttpResponse save( @PathVariable @Nullable Long id, @Body Map body ){
    def o = bindFromIdAndBody id, body

    if( o.save( flush:true ) ){
      log.info "version >> $o.version"
      HttpResponse.ok o
    }else{
      log.info '-------------------------'
      List errors = o.errors.fieldErrors.collect{ FieldError fe ->
        fe.codes.findResult{ String c -> 
          messageSource.getMessage c, fe.arguments, null, Locale.default
        } ?: fe.codes.last()
      }
      log.info "save failed for $o: $errors"
      HttpResponse.badRequest( errors:errors )
    }
  }
```

When I call the action, I'm getting `400 Bad Request` in my client, but instead of `{ errors:[ {..}, {..}, {..} ]` style JSON, I see rather:

```
{
  "message":"Validation Error(s) occurred during save() : Field error in object ...  default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be blank]\r\n",
  "path":"fullName",
  "_links":{"self":{"href":"/person/42","templated":false}}
}
```

Also the `else{}` block is never reached, I don't get any further logs.

Any hints?

Comment: It is difficult to say for sure what is going wrong because you haven't shown what the body of the request looks like, it isn't clear what `o` is and it isn't clear what the `save(Map)` method you are invoking on `o` does.  Is it the case that you have a constrained property in whatever class `o` is an instance of that is named `fullName` and `fullName` is not accounted for in the body of the request?  If so, is `fullName` a property which is derived from other properties which are accounted for in the request?

Comment: `o` is in this case an instance of GORM `Person` domain class, which has a non-blank `fullName` property. The strange thing is, that almost the same code works fine in vertx route and ratpack handler, and I'm pretty sure would work the same way in Grails as well

Comment: "Also the else{} block is never reached" - There is some piece of the puzzle missing here because from what you show, it almost requires a bug in the JVM for that to be the case unless the call to `.save` is throwing an exception, which I assume you would have mentioned.  If I could see it in an app it might be easy to diagnose.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown see my answer pls. I think this should be mentioned in the ref-doc somehow.

Comment: I didn't realize that a `ValidationException` was being thrown.  That would have been easy to diagnose had I known that.  I am sorry for the noise.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown yep, I saw no traces of `ValidationException` too until I put `try-catch` around`save()`.

Comment: " I saw no traces of ValidationException" - Right.  The evidence that an exception was being thrown is that neither the `if` nor the `else` block was executing.  The only way for that to happen is a bug in the JVM or the call to `.save` threw an exception.  I am glad you got it worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears, that in GORM configuration for Micronaut done via

```
  compile 'io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-hibernate-gorm'
```

the `failOnError` is set to `true` by default. That led to `ValidationException` being thrown on `save()` instead of populating `o.errors`.

To fix the issue I added the line

```
grails.gorm.failOnError: false
```

to my `application.yml` and now it's working like charm.